# Confused on how exactly to use Regex?

Tags: java, regex

So I've been looking at a lot of searches when it came to regex expressions, however i'm still pretty confused on how to set them up. The issue I'm having is that i'm trying to convert this given text given from an input file:

```
(42, 10) d (23, 1) (123, 4) (32, 10) d (12, 9)
```

such that I can stick it into an String array where it looks like this:

```
[42, 10, d, 23, 1, 123, 4, 32, 10, d, 12, 9]
```

Any tips?
I tried using a delimiter at first to get rid of the parentheses and commas however, delimiters puts each value on a whole separate line which sadly isn't what I'm aiming for. I'm essentially trying to ignore those special characters so I can assign for example 42 to an int a, and 10 to int b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What language are you using?  EDIT: nvm I see you're using Java.  Premise is still there on how to do it, I'll get back to you in a bit with the Java version.

In perl this would be pretty simple.

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $var = "(42, 10) d (23, 1) (123, 4) (32, 10) d (12, 9)";

$var =~ s/\)/,/g;
$var =~ s/\(//g;
$var =~ s/d/d,/g;
$var =~ s/\s*//g;
my @arr = split /,/, $var;
print Dumper \@arr;
```

Java Version:

```
    String content = "(42, 10) d (23, 1) (123, 4) (32, 10) d (12, 9)";
    String[] split = null;

    split = content.replace(")",",").replace("(","").replace("d","d,").replace(" ","").split(",");

    for (String a : split)
    {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

Although I guess this doesn't strictly answer your question, since it doesn't use regex.  It just uses replace and split.

Comment: it's perfectly fine thank you! regex wasn't mandatory however, I was just told that would be one of the easiest ways to accomplish what I was going for so I've been trying to do research on it for the past few hours.

Comment: Ah.  I see.  Well if you still want to go the regex path, this regex would work:  /(\d*)|\d/g  I'm not sure how that would fit in to how java works, but in perl it would simply be my @arr = ( $var =~ /\d+|d/g );

Perl regexes btw are the defacto standard for regexes, so if you ever want to learn more about regexes I would suggest playing with perl as using regexes in perl is muuuuuuch easier than pretty much any other language based on the syntax for manipulating and using the outputs of regexes.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want regex, then this works better when there is more complexity in your data.

Note: I just do alphanumeric data, since the `d` didn't seem to mean anything special

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z0-9]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("(42, 10) d (23, 1) (123, 4) (32, 10) d (12, 9)");

String delim = ",";
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("[");
while (m.find()) {
    sb.append(m.group()).append(delim);
}
sb.setLength(sb.length() - delim.length());
System.out.println(sb.append("]").toString());
```

Output

```
[42,10,d,23,1,123,4,32,10,d,12,9]
```

Use a `List<String>` if you do want to keep that data around.

Comment: hm ok, I think i get how this code works. Thank you also! I'll probably look at both of those and try to work with both with the rest of my program and see if I can make either work. Thank you again!